# Force-Close-Error by receiveing a Intent

Tags: android, error-handling, android-intent

**What I try to do**

---

I got a ListView, with a OnItemClick in it, there I get the URL which I stored into, with this URL I set an Intent to an other Activity(WebView) to open up, the webpage.

**Question**

---

When I try to get the Intent, I allways get a Force-Close-Error but I don't get why. It would be great if you find out whats wrong :(

The Code of both Activitys you find down here:

**Code**

---

test2.java -> Here I create the Intent

```
package de.stepforward;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import de.stepforward.web.ShowVideo;



import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;



public class test2 extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    String result = "";
    String line = null;
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    //get the Data from URL
    try{
    URL url = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/TheStepForward/uploads?alt=json&format=1"); 

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    //read d response till d end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    result = sb.toString();
    Log.v("log_tag", "Append String " + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try{
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject feed = json.getJSONObject("feed");
        JSONArray entrylist = feed.getJSONArray("entry");

        for(int i=0;i<entrylist.length();i++){
            //Get Title
            JSONObject movie = entrylist.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject title = movie.getJSONObject("title");
            String txtTitle = title.getString("$t");
            Log.d("Title", txtTitle);

            //Get Description
            JSONObject content = movie.getJSONObject("content");
            String txtContent = content.getString("$t");
            Log.d("Content", txtContent);

            //Get Link
            JSONArray linklist = movie.getJSONArray("link");
            JSONObject link = linklist.getJSONObject(0);
            String txtLink = link.getString("href");
            Log.d("Link", txtLink);


            //Get Thumbnail
            JSONObject medialist = movie.getJSONObject("media$group");
            JSONArray thumblist = medialist.getJSONArray("media$thumbnail");
            JSONObject thumb = thumblist.getJSONObject(2);
            String txtThumb = thumb.getString("url");
            Log.d("Thumb", txtThumb.toString());


            //String Array daraus machen und in Hashmap füllen
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Thumb", txtThumb);
            map.put("Title", txtTitle);
            map.put("Content", txtContent);
            map.put("Link", txtLink);
            mylist.add(map);

        }
        //ListView füllen
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.lit, 
                new String[] { "Thumb","Title","Content","Link"}, 
                new int[] { R.id.img_video,R.id.txt_title,R.id.txt_subtitle});      
        setListAdapter(adapter);


        //OnClickLister um Youtube-Video zu öffnen
        final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    //Video-Link auslesen
                    Map<String, String> map = mylist.get(position);
                    String link = map.get("Link");
                    Log.d("Link", link);

                    final Intent Showvideo = new Intent(test2.this, ShowVideo.class);
                    Showvideo.putExtra("VideoLink", link);

                    final Intent i = new Intent(test2.this, ShowVideo.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });



    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
}
}
```

---

Showvideo.java -> Here I receive the Intent

```
package de.stepforward.web;

import de.stepforward.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class ShowVideo extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showvideo);


    //Video-Link abfangen
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String VideoLink = extras.getString("ShowVideo");


    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(VideoLink);



    }




}
```

---

Thank you for the help in advance!

Best Regards

safari

Note: Sorry forget the Error-Log. Here you are:

**Error-Log**

```
11-29 08:57:57.258: W/dalvikvm(10944): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.stepforward/de.stepforward.web.ShowVideo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at de.stepforward.web.ShowVideo.onCreate(ShowVideo.java:33)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
11-29 08:57:57.258: E/AndroidRuntime(10944):    ... 11 more
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please write variable names with a small letter and class names with a big letter at the beginning. And Camel-case in every name;

So to your question I think the two answers should fix it. Just to have it in one place, your onItemClick method should look like this.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                //Video-Link auslesen
                Map<String, String> map = myList.get(position);
                String link = map.get("Link");
                Log.d("Link", link);

                Intent i = new Intent(test2.this, ShowVideo.class);
                i.putExtra("VideoLink", link);
                startActivity(i);

            }
```

Firstly you don't have to create 2 intents. You just create one and give the context and the the class in the constructor and put the data in the same intent. The ShowVideo Activity doesn't know anything about your second Intent. You save the extra with the key "VideoLink" and want to get the extra with the key "ShowVideo". You have to use the same key otherwise you won't get anything out of it. The error is because your extras are null and that could be because you don't add any data to your real intent. You have to use one intent for the class and the data.

the onCreate should look like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.showvideo);


//Video-Link abfangen
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String videoLink = extras.getString("VideoLink");

....

}
```

Secondly I would make a static constant in the ShowVideo Activity for your extra name.
So at the top of the ShowVideo add

```
public static final String EXTRA_VIDEO_LINK = "VideoLink";
```

and instead of the "VideoLink" in your put and get extra you write ShowVideo.EXTRA_VIDEO_LINK
That will prevent that you unintentionally have different keys.

Answer (score 1):

at put time you write this line

```
Showvideo.putExtra("VideoLink", link);
```

and at get time you write

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String VideoLink = extras.getString("ShowVideo");
```

as you have to use same key for getting and setting time as per your case you set the VideoLink as key and getting time use ShowVideo which is not set

try this way

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String VideoLink = extras.getString("VideoLink");
```

Comment: i changed it like you told me, but i still get the same Force-Close-Error :(

Answer (score 1):

What is this? why you wrote 2 intent and passing extra to another intent.

```
  final Intent Showvideo = new Intent(test2.this, ShowVideo.class);
                        Showvideo.putExtra("VideoLink", link);

                        final Intent i = new Intent(test2.this, ShowVideo.class);
                        startActivity(i);
```

In this ShowVideo Activity you are getting extras as key is "ShowVideo". but you are passing that as "VideoLink".

```
 String VideoLink = extras.getString("ShowVideo");
```

this is why you are getting nullpointer in getting the extras line 33.

Comment: yes i wrote one, to start the activity, the otherone to overgive the url ;)

Comment: if(extras!=null){ String VideoLink = extras.getString("VideoLink"); }  your link is coming as null i think so. try this above line.

Comment: it seems extra is null, but why the hell?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final Intent Showvideo = new Intent(test2.this, ShowVideo.class);
Showvideo.putExtra("VideoLink", link);
startActivity(Showvideo);
```